# Extend not override module in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Let us say that I want to extend a module. At the same time I do not want to override its properties. In JavaScript I would do:

```
var root = this; // window
(function(exports) {
    if ('widget' in exports) return;

    function widget() {
        //
    }

    exports.widget = widget;

})(root.library || (root.library = {}));
```

It would seem that TypeScript offers the same using `module`. But using it the following way will indiscriminately override any `widget` property previously defined on `library`:

```
module library {
    export function widget() {
        //
    }
}
```

Now I could use the former but then TypeScript complains about nesting a `class` definition if I create one inside the function. If I place the definition outside the function then it becomes exported (say on `window`) which is what I want to avoid.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the motivation for avoiding class-based inheritance for this?

Comment: @SteveFenton can you provide an example? My answer at the bottom does what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK **user error**, the following works fine and the only warning I am getting is *return outside function definition* but that is not a TypeScript error:

```
module library {
    if (library.widget) {
        return;
    }

    class Internal {

    }

    export function widget() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with vars:

```
module library {
    export var  widget = function () {
        //
    }
}

module library{
    if(library.widget){
        return;
    }
    else{
        library.widget = function(){            
        }   
    }   
}
```

[Try it.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20library%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20var%20%20widget%20=%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Amodule%20library%7B%0A%09if%28library.widget%29%7B%0A%09%09return;%0A%09%7D%0A%09else%7B%0A%09%09library.widget%20=%20function%28%29%7B%09%09%09%0A%09%09%7D%09%0A%09%7D%09%0A%7D)

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is a simple example using class-based inheritance to supply a widget and then a specialised version of a widget. This allows you to re-use code in the original widget and substitute different types of widget for each other without changing calling code.

```
module Example {
    export class WidgetBase {
        doWidgetThings() {
            return 'Base widget things';
        }

        doOtherThings() {
            return 'Base other things';
        }
    }

    export class WidgetSpecialisation extends WidgetBase {
        doWidgetThings() {
            return 'Special widget things';
        }

        doOtherThings() {
            return super.doOtherThings();
        }
    }
}

var widget = new Example.WidgetSpecialisation();
alert(widget.doWidgetThings() + ' ' + widget.doOtherThings());
```

Comment: Sorry Steve, I have not described my question well. The idea is that I am embedding my widget on a page that I know nothing about. So I simply want to add properties to a module but if that module already has those properties, return.